# share xcode projects

Tags: xcode, macos, file-sharing, code-sharing

I searched this but I haven't found the exact answer I'm looking for. I'm trying to email a friend/co-worker a saved xcode project I'm working on. If I send attach my saved file in an email when he opens it up everything is kinda red and theres no code or anything. How can I send the whole project so that he can access it? Thanks.

Comment: And what files are you sending him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are sending him just the Xcode project file, but you will need all the source files.

If you assume your project is in:

```
/Users/me/Projects/MyDeadGoodProject/
    MyDeadGoodProject                     (folder with source)
    MyDeadGoodProject.xcodeproj           (project bundle)
```

(Which is fairly standard)

Then you need to send the whole of the top-level project directory structure.

This is best done by zipping up the whole lot, which can be done from *Finder* by right-clicking and selecting "Compress MyDeadGoodProject" or from the command line (Terminal.app) using `zip`:

```
$ cd ~/Projects
$ zip -r9 MyDeadGoodProject.zip MyDeadGoodProject
```

And then e-mail him the .zip file.

If you co-operate with someone else on a regular basic then it's best to get some central git hosting going, as that will be **much** easier to manage.

Comment: cool I'll definitely look into that git hosting you mentioned. until I get that set up ill try your zip method. Thanks for your help.